# Do rebase again after squash to different branch

Tags: git

I have the following scenario

I checked out branch1 from master. Did some work on that and put that for code review.

I checkout out branch2 from branch1 to do additional work on top of work in branch1 while branch1 is in review

I fixed reviews and squashed the commits in branch1 to single commit and pushed to master.

I rebase branch1 to branch2 but get conflicts. How to handle this scenario the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem when rebasing branch2 is that you might rebase old commits from the old branch1 branch (before you squashed its commits)

Make sure to rebase only the new commits from branch2: get the first new branch2 commit SHA1, and do, on your new branch1 HEAD (squashed):

```
git rebase --onto branch1 <first commit of branch2 SHA1> branch2
```

That will rebase only the commits you want, and minimize the conflicts.

Comment: I might have not explained correctly. branch1 had commit c1. I forked branch2 from it so branch2 also has c1. I did additional work on branch1 so commit looks like c1 c2. I squashed c1 c2 into one commit c3 and pushed to mainline. Now when I do git checkout branch2 and git rebase branch1, I get conflicts because I squashed the branch and so commit changed. How to fix this?

Comment: @coderhacker So you have similar works done both of branch1 and branch2? Why not reset branch2 on branch1, and go on from there?

Comment: Thanks, got a better understanding of onto.